# css how to add a navigation bar under other navigation bar

Tags: css, html, navigationbar

I wanted to make another navigation bar under the first navigation bar but It's not working how to change my css to achieve what I want?[image]

This is my css coding

```
.firstnav
{
float:left;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:80px;
}

.secondnav
{
float:left;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-right: 80px;
}


ul li
{
display: inline-block;
}


ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
transition: 0.6s ease;

}


ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
color:#000;
}


ul li .active a
{
    background-color: #fff;
color: #000;

}


.logo img
{
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
}

    .main
{
max-width: 1500px;
margin: auto;
}
```

and this is my html coding

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
<ul class="firstnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="secondnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

I have try lots of ways to solve this but still in problem, I try to change the .secondnav margin but its not working, it move weird not horizontal and vertical, it move oblique.

Comment: what I want is the second bar can appear under the first bar

Comment: someone help me to solve this problem please.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` to `firstnav/secondnav` instead `inline-block`

and set `justify-content: flex-end;` to `secondnav` to `float right`

See code below and mark up:https://jsfiddle.net/tq27n1xg/5/

```css
body {
    background: black;
}
.firstnav
{
    padding-left: 0;
  display:flex;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top:50px;
}

.secondnav
{
display:flex;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 30px;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
transition: 0.6s ease;

}


ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
color:#000;
}


ul li .active a
{
 background-color: #fff;
color: #000;

}


.logo img
{
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
}

    .main
{
max-width: 1500px;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
<ul class="firstnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="secondnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

**Tou your comment:**

> the first bar home alignment with the second bar home

use `display:flex` to `main` and use `margin-top: 57px;` to second:https://jsfiddle.net/tq27n1xg/17/

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: its not working ..it shows that cant use in current scheme and also it did'n change anything as well..

Comment: nope :/ but example in fiddle will help  me to solve issuse:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: do you mean the second will start  under contact of first?

Comment: owhh ok...nvm then I'll try it myself hahah

Comment: means right parallel with the first bar, contact under the second bar will parallel with the contact at the first bar

Comment: show me what you tried(after add code click on save/update button) and attach the url

Comment: ...I'm trying to use it but idk how to display the css

Comment: put the css in css section(you have html,css and js)

Comment: do you need it responsive?

Comment: just need to change the current position of the second bar.

Comment: the first bar home alignment with the second bar home

Comment: second bar under first bar

Comment: emm....nvm I think I will investigate it by myself ya.. because its still not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

try to use display:flex

replace your css with this code

```
    .main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.firstnav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around
}
.secondnav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around
}
```

and then add the styling you want.

this code only position the navs the way you wanted.

Comment: this make my navigation bar become so weird.. the space between the tag become too far away.

Comment: you can adjust the width of main to be shorter then 100% 
also you can read here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
about flex box 
justify-content have many possibilities.